# define chart.js tooltip width

Tags: tooltip, chart.js2

I added as a callback custom string to afterLabel in chart.js tooltip.

```
tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          afterLabel: function (tooltipItems, data) {
            return 'my nice string'
          }
        }
      },
```

I am using default tooltip and if possible would like to continue so. Problem is that "afterLabel" comes at a new line and I haven't found where to define the width (or remove line break). Question is similar. How do I define width of tooltip and/or remove the line break.